# Passing Co-ordinates from one view to another

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3

Now i am updating the code with the perfect output. This may help my friends to place the correct markers.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

placevcViewController.h

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    #import 
    #import "fetchurl.h"
    #import

```
@interface placevcViewController : UIViewController
{
    CLLocationDegrees lat;
    CLLocationDegrees lng;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D local;
}
-(id)init;
-(void)location:(CLLocationManager *)address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *location;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *addressfeild;
@property (strong, nonatomic) fetchurl *fu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GMSMapView *map;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GMSCameraPosition *camera;
@end
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

placevcViewController.m

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
#import "placevcViewController.h"

@interface placevcViewController ()

@end

@implementation placevcViewController
@synthesize addressfeild, map,fu,locationManager,camera;
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
     location = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0.0",@"lat",@"0.0",@"lng",@"Null Island",@"adress",@"NULL Home",@"name", nil];
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    lng = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    local = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);

    fu = [[fetchurl alloc]init];

    camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat longitude: lng zoom:12];
    map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480) camera:camera];
    [self.view addSubview:map];
        map.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(200, 65, 100, 40);
    [button setTitle:@"SEARCH" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(search:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    addressfeild = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 68, 200, 30)];
    addressfeild.placeholder = @"SEARCH";
    [addressfeild setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:addressfeild];

}
 -(IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
    [self location:str1];
}
 -(void)location:(NSString *)address
{
    NSString *baseUrl =@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@location=%@&radius=10000&name=dominos&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCczXEpxw19qAXQMEUUA98OsMaOESNSOjM",baseUrl,address];
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *queryUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSLog(@"query url%@",queryUrl);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:queryUrl];
        [self fetchData:data];
    });
}

-(void)fetchData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *data1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    // NSLog(@"Response data: %@", data1);
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray* results =[json objectForKey:@"results"];
    //NSLog(@"Data is:%@" ,results);
    for (int i = 0;i <[results count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *result = [results objectAtIndex:i];
        // NSLog(@"Data is %@", result);
        NSString *address = [result objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
        // NSLog(@"Address is %@", address);
        NSString *name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
        //NSLog(@"name is %@", name);
        NSDictionary *geometry = [result objectForKey: @"geometry"];
        NSDictionary *locations = [geometry objectForKey:@"location"];
        NSString *lat =[locations objectForKey:@"lat"];
        NSString *lng =[locations objectForKey:@"lng"];
        //NSLog(@"longitude is %@", lng);
        NSDictionary *gc = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:lat,@"lat",lng,@"lng",address,@"address",name,@"name", nil];
        location = gc;
        double lat1 = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"Marker position%f",lat1);
        double lng1 = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"Marker position%f",lng1);
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D local = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, lng1);

        marker.position = local;
        marker.title = [ location objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"Address is %@",marker.title);
        marker.snippet = [location objectForKey:@"address"];
        marker.map = map;
        GMSCameraUpdate *cams = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:local zoom:12];
        [map animateWithCameraUpdate:cams];
    }

}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am facing trouble with the functions which i bolded up. Actually i want to pass the co-ordinates of my current location from  **placevcViewController.m** to **fetchurl.m** through a function **-(void)location:(CLLocationManager *)address withCallback:(SEL)sel withDelegate:        (id)delegate;** , but somehow it is not working. Either the function is incorrect or i am not using the correct data type for fetching the co-ordinates.

Updates :
       **I have update the above code in fetchurl.m file(you can c ** there the code within the stars is upadted ) , and the updation is helping me to get the array of multiple locations. But now i am not getting how to add the marker on each location**.

Comment: I have update the above code in fetchurl.m file(you can c ** there the code within the stars is upadted ) , and the updation is helping me to get the array of multiple locations. But now i am not getting how to add the marker on each location.

Answer (score 0):

To use the delegate-protocol pattern successfully, you need some additional setup:

PlacevcViewController.h needs to define both a delegate property, and define the protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

//at the bottom of your file, below the @interface ... @end
@protocol nameOfYourProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)methodForDoingSomething:(SomeClass*)argument;

@end
```

Then within PlacevcViewController.m you can call your delegate method like this:

```
[self.delegate methodForDoingSomething:anArgument];
```

Then you assign your delegate and implement the method in the target class (fetchUrl.h in your case)

```
//declare conformity to the protocol like this in the header file
@interface fetchurl : NSObject <nameOfYourProtocol>
```

and finally in the fetchUrl.m file:

```
//assign the delegate to self when creating an instance of fetchUrl
fu = [[fetchUrl alloc] init];
[fu setDelegate:self];

//implement the delegate method
- (void)methodForDoingSomething:(SomeClass*)argument {
    //your code goes here
}
```

While there is nothing right or wrong about using the delegate-protocol pattern, from what I can tell of your example a simpler approach might be to just define a method within `fetchUrl` that returns the items you need and let the owner of that instance of fetchUrl handle it. ie:

```
- (NSDictionary*)fetchData:(NSData*)data {
    //do the work and create a dictionary

    //return theDictionary
   }
```

and then just consume the result in your placevcViewController:

```
NSDictionary* results = [fu fetchData:someData];
//now work with the results
```

Comment: While it's not absolutely required for the code to compile, you should always name your classes with a Capital letter to start, and let instances be lowercase. PlacevcViewController and FetchUrl are the class names, then instances may start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I have update the above code in fetchurl.m file(you can c ** there the code within the stars is upadted ) , and the updation is helping me to get the array of multiple locations. But now i am not getting how to add the marker on each location.